# Azure Data factory and Power Query

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, powerquery

I am using Azure Data Factory and Power Query.

I have setup a linked service and dataset that successfully connects to an Azure Gen-2 Data Lake storage account.

When I create a new power query and set it to the dataset the following message is returned...

[image]

The word 'undefined' is getting set in the power query call to the Az storage account and not the account url - when I manually paste the actual Az storage account url the power query works and returns the data however when I save the power the query goes back to 'undefined'

```
let
  AdfDoc = AzureStorage.DataLakeContents("**undefined**/data-lake/CovidLoad/Report.csv"),
  Csv = Csv.Document(AdfDoc, [Delimiter = ",", Encoding = TextEncoding.Utf8, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.Csv]),
  PromotedHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv, [PromoteAllScalars = true])
in
  PromotedHeaders
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you setting the dataset in the ADF UI or in the M script directly?

Comment: A SAS token is successfully being retrieved from key-vault and it is the token that is used to connect to the storage account. Possible an issue using an SAS token with power-query in ADF?

Comment: When I set the linked service to connection to the storage account using the account-url and account- key the power-query works OK - it returns data

Answer (score 0):

When I set the linked service to connection to the storage account using the account-url and account- key the power-query works OK - it returns data